# Equal Usage of Each Variable in an Array

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, web

If there is an application that fetches data from a server by sending a request to the server with the id of the server,

Application Request = (main request) + (id of the server the request will be sent to)

Assuming that the applications save the server ids in an array and whenever sending requests, they pick up a server id from the array, and send the request to the server having that id.

And there are 5 servers, and each server can handle a maximum of 10,000 requests per day.

I would like to know how can it be assured that if there are around 40,000 daily requests sent by the app, then the requests will be equally divided to the 5 servers, and none of the servers will get overloaded.
Also, the applications are distributed on different independent phones, so they cannot communicate with each other regarding to which server have they sent how many requests. And there cannot be another php server counting the requests.

Would appreciate some help in figuring out on how I can put almost equal load to each server. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is called load balancing and it should be left upto the server to handle this.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)

I don't know if this article will be of any use:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html